# Caption box on my slideshow jumps when you refresh cache

Tags: views

When you access my site for the first time, the caption box on the slideshow starts lower by about 50px then adjusts itself to the correct position. Pressing Ctrl-F5 also recreates the problem.

Is there a way I can set a breakpoint within the CSS or Drupal so I can step through to find whats causing the problem? Also, any clues whats causing the problem?

thanks

website: www.terrafirmasouth.co.uk

Comment: interestingly, when I remove the pager block underneath , the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

This is a css problem, sorry. If I add position:absolute to my pagers block then the jumping stops, however, my pager block then appears under the text below the slide and the pagers cant be clicked on. I will follow up on stack overflow for css queries.

Comment: Thats fantastic! Never new about z-index. I have added it to my pagers block below, and it works, i now get the pagers back as links which I can click. 
however, I cant seem to get any margin or padding at the bottom, it just ignores it, not sure why?
    .views-slideshow-controls-bottom {

 position: absolute;
 text-align:center;
 width: 100%;
 z-index:1;


    }